# Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'decimal'.

Tags: c#, casting, dbnull, explicit-conversion

sdr is my sqldatareader and I want to check that the curPrice value which is of type decimal is null.

`inrec.curPrice = sdr.IsDBNull(7) ? (decimal?)null : sdr.GetDecimal(7);`

This is the error message I am getting:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'decimal'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Where am I going wrong, please someone tell me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

either convert `curPrice` to nullable, or use .Value property of nullable types.

If `curPrice` is a property of a class then

```
public decimal? curPrice
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

Answer (score 31):

`decimal?` indicates that it's a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) decimal; you have to use the `Value` property to get the actual value (if it exists, determined via `HasValue`).

I'm assuming `curPrice` is a non-nullable decimal, in which case you need to also figure out a better value to return than `null` from the true side of your ternary operator.

Comment: I'm confused. Would you happen to have code samples to explain what you mean..real sorry this is very new to me.

Answer (score 6):

```
inrec.curPrice = sdr.GetValueOrDefault(0m)
```

Since the left side (`Price`) does not allow for `null` then you cannot set its value to something that could be `null`. Therefore, use `.GetValueOrDefault(decimal defaultValue)` to return a default value when `null`.

Answer (score 4):

How about converting the `decmial?` type to `decimal` ?

You have to have what value you like `inrec.curPrice` to have when `sdr.GetDecmial(7)` is null.

```
inrec.curPrice = sdr.GetDecimal(7) ?? 0M;
```

I assumed that you would want to use 0 if what's returned was null.  If not change `0M` to some other decimal value.

--- Update after replay

How about `inrec.curPrice = sdr.IsDBNull(7) ? 0M : sdr.GetDecimal(7);` ?

Comment: When I do that, I get this error: Error 7 Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'decimal'

Comment: Ah.. I just looked up `.GetDecimal()` in MDSN, It returns a `decimal` and not `decimal?` so my answer was nonsense.  Sorry about that.